# Segmentation Fault in function pointer

Tags: c

I have an example code as below, because I'm not familiar with the function pointer so that I cannot find out what is happening at 
ret = (p_local->str)(10,b_in); (segmentation fault)

```
#include "stdio.h"

typedef int (*check)(const int a, char * const b[]);

typedef struct ST_T_COMMAND
{
    char *chuoi;
    check str;
} T_COMMAND;

const T_COMMAND *p_global;

int main()
{
    int ret;
    const T_COMMAND *p_local;
    char *b_in[] = {"1234", "abchd"};
    T_COMMAND str_new;

    p_global = &str_new;
    str_new.chuoi = "1234";
    p_local = p_global;

    if(strcmp(p_local->chuoi, b_in[0]) == 0)
    {
        ret = (p_local->str)(10, b_in);
        printf("ret = %d\n", ret);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("else\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I want to pass that segmentation fault. And please tell me what is wrong with my code

Comment: You've assigned something to `str_new.chuoi` with `str_new.chuoi = "1234";` But you didn't assign anything to `str_new.str` You can't use `str` unless it has a valid pointer to a function.

Comment: Read [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and enable all warnings when compiling your code: with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) use `gcc -g -Wall`

Comment: @Basile And `-Wextra`, and if you're really after it, `-pedantic`.

Comment: `warning: ‘str_new.str’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]`: it requires `-Wall -Wextra -O3`  with GCC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
typedef int (*check)(const int a, char * const b[]);
```

you have declared the **function pointer** i.e `check` is the function pointer name, it can points to any function whose input argument are `int` and `char* const []` type & which returns `int` type.

And here

```
ret = (p_local->str)(10, b_in); /* calling via function pointer */
```

you are trying to call via function pointer but *you haven't initialized function pointer anywhere*. You need to **initialize function pointer first before calling** it.

Also

```
const T_COMMAND *p_local; /* initialize it here itself */
```

above syntax means where `p_local` points that is constant i.e when you will do  like

```
p_local->str = funHandler;
```

as I did below, compiler will not allow it to modify.

Same with `p_global`, if you make this as `const` earlier, you can't do like

```
const T_COMMAND *p_global;
p_local = p_global; /* not possible due to above const declaration of p_global */
```

Try this version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef int (*check)(const int a, char * const b[]);
typedef struct ST_T_COMMAND
{
    char *chuoi;
    check str;
}T_COMMAND;

T_COMMAND *p_global; /* removed const */
int funHandler(int num, char* const buf[10])
{
    printf("in funHandler() %d %s\n", num, buf[0]);
    return num;
}
int main(void)
{
    int ret;
    T_COMMAND *p_local; /* removed const */
    char * b_in[] = {"1234","abchd"};
    T_COMMAND str_new;
    p_global = &str_new;
    str_new.chuoi = "1234";
    p_local = p_global;

    if(strcmp(p_local->chuoi,b_in[0]) == 0) 
    {
        p_local->str = funHandler; /* initialize function pointer, you missed this */
        ret = (p_local->str)(10,b_in);
        printf("ret = %d\n",ret);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("else\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "above syntax means you can't reassign p_local hereafter this declaration due to const" - this is not correct; `const` is part of what's pointed to, not the pointer itself. Example - `const char *x;  x = "foo";`

Comment: yes agree @M.M here pointer is not constant. Will edit.

Answer (score 1):

```
 ret = (p_local->str)(10,b_in);
```

You are calling the function `p_local->str` without initializing it first.

You need to set a value to `plocal->str` (or any of the equivalent values in your program i.e. `p_global`, `str_new`)

This value should be a function that you have defined elsewhere which matches the type of the function pointer i.e. parameters of `const int a` and `char * const b[]`